# How to read & write first line of text file in C#?

Tags: c#, text

I need to write first line of a text file, which is a name of the company while the other 3 lines is information (described in class).

I have a text file like this:

```
Turistines keliones;
Poilsine; 7; Italija; 500; Atostogauti;
Pazintine; 5; Cekija; 200; Pamatyti;
Turistine; 4; Kroatija; 350; Ivairiai;
```

I have written this and I don't know how to write the name.

```
static void SpausdintiKeliones(string fv, List<Firma1> _firmosKeliones)
    {
        using (var fr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(fv, FileMode.Append), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
        {                                
            fr.WriteLine("| Nr. | Keliones tipas | Keliones trukme (dienomis) |  Vietove  | Kaina (eurais) | Keliones aprasymas |");
            for (int i = 0; i < _firmosKeliones.Count; i++)
            {
                Firma1 kelione = _firmosKeliones[i];
                fr.WriteLine("|{0, 4} {1}", i + 1, kelione);
            }
            fr.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't want it to start with a blank line, stop adding a blank line with `fr.WriteLine("");`

Comment: `fr.WriteLine("");` writes a blank line, if you want anything else instead, change `""` to whatever you want to write to the file. If that doesn't answer your question, please add more detail.

Comment: What do you mean with "_read & write first line_"? Why do you need to read **AND** write the first line? Your question currently doesn't make much sense... Please **EDIT**, clarify and improve your question so we, the readers, actually have a chance to understand what your problem is...

Answer (score -1):

You are adding the blank line inside your method.

Consider removing the line:

```
fr.WriteLine("");
```